# how to get actual data in checkpoint in qtp?

Tags: qtp

i am new to qtp, i want get the data in chekpoint, i am not asking about checkpoint return value, what ever checkpoint capture data, that data put display in msgbox.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve. Standard checkpoints retrieve values for specific properties and compare it to the value that the object had when the checkpoint was created. If you want to see the current values you should use `GetROProperty(propName)`.

As for which properties are captured in the checkpoint, that is determined when the checkpoint is created and can be viewed/edited later (right click on the checkpoint object and click properties).

If this doesn't answer your question please try to clarify it.

Comment: I, too, do understand he wants to get a grab on the data that the checkpoint checks. So GetROProperty is the way to go. (If the app updates itself asynchroneously, this might yield a value different from the value a previous checkpoint saw, though.)